# Why `python main.py\` (different with `python main.py`) executable on Windows?

Tags: python

```py
# a.py, with `import b` version.
print("# With `import b`")
import sys, b
print(sys.path)
```

```py
# a.py, without `import b` version.
print("# Without `import b`")
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

```py
# b.py
print('b.py executed')
```

When I execute `python a.py`(With `import b` version), `import b` works well but `python a.py\` not.
I run it on Windows 11. I guess this happen's only on Windows, not linux.

When I check system path using `sys.path`, `python a.py\` contains:
`(currentDir)/a.py`, not `(currentDir)`

I wonder why `python main.py\` is executable on Windows. And I guess it could induce some bugs for python-based programs.

[click here to view what is going here on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsRvg.png)

Comment: You have circular imports. This isn't supposed to work.

Comment: @Barmar: The behaviour of circular imports is well-defined, and the circular aspect isn’t related to this question.

Comment: I admit I'm confused by this question. On Unix, backslash escapes the newline so the command is continued on the next line. I don't know what it does in the Windows CLI.

Comment: @Barmar on Windows, backslash is the path separator, thus ``python a.py\`` tries to run a directory named "a.py" as a module (ie. it looks for `a.py\__main__.py`).

Comment: Just checking - this is run within Command Prompt/Powershell?

Comment: @SuperStormer I ran this on `Windows Powershell`, but same thing happens on command prompt(cmd.exe)

Comment: Important: The examples in the image actually have a path component, like this: `python .\research\a.py` etc.

Comment: @milk, you should print out `sys.path` _before_  trying to `import b`, so you can see what is in it when the import fails.

Comment: @alexis of course, when I tried as what you said, same thing happen. printing sys.path. `(currentDir)/a.py` is on `sys.path`, not `(currentDir)`.

Comment: Glad to hear that, but nothing is "of course" when you are investigating unexpected behavior. The output you provide confirms @SuperStormer's analysis of the problem, though. Python can find the file, but it is misparsed when sys.path is constructed.

Comment: Are you sure that both a.py and b.py are regular files (and not directories, symlinks, hardlinks, etc)? As written, I can't reproduce your scenario.

Comment: @SuperStormer of course, a.py and b.py are regular file. not directory, not symlink, not hardlink, etc. I guess something could change if you try same scenario on "Windows Terminal", if you use Windows 10(not Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, backslash is the path separator, thus `python a.py\` tries to run a directory named "a.py" as a module (ie. it looks for `a.py\__main__.py`). In your case, Python will error with a message that looks something like this:

```
can't open file 'c:\some\path\here\a.py\': [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

because "a.py" is actually a file, so attempting to treat it as a directory fails.

Comment: This makes sense, but the question claims that it's actually running, not getting an error. The only difference is whether `import b` works.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a good point. I still think the part about running as a module applies, though I'm also confused as to how the original command succeeded in the first place.

Comment: @SuperStormer I erased circular import part, which is not important on this question. And since you misunderstood my question, I attached reference image to view.